# Replace javascript popup window with jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am making a custom theme for [webtrees](http://webtrees.net). webtrees uses a lot of popup windows and I want to replace them with jquery dialogs, but I don't want to mess with the core code. So the jquery script has to override the original function and onclick event. I have searched all over the internet but didn't find a solution. Hope some of you can help me.

This is one of the functions I want to override:

```
var helpWin;
function helpPopup(which, mod) {
    if (which==null) which = "help_contents_help";
    if (mod!='') which=which+'&mod='+mod;
    if ((!helpWin)||(helpWin.closed)) {
        helpWin = window.open('help_text.php?help='+which,'_blank','left=50,top=50,width=500,height=320,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
    } else {
        helpWin.location = 'help_text.php?help='+which;
    }
    return false;
}
function closeHelp() {
    if (helpWin) helpWin.close();
}
```

The html looks something like this:

```
<a class="help" onclick="helpPopup('index_charts','charts'); return false;" href="#">
```

I tried several jquery solutions for jquery dialog but none of them worked.

Any solution?

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?  I would think you should, since you need `click` in quotes, like this: `'click'`

Comment: No I don't get any errors. And this is not my function but a core function of webtrees that I am trying to override. I just giving this function to make clear what the current popup function is, but I want to replace this with a jquery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sottenad/b2JY9/

You should be able to replace the window.open calls with $.ajax calls, then plumb the dialog to display the content you get back. then either open the dialog, or if its already open, just replace the existing content.

Note: the fiddle wont execute, but its much easier to read the code there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not a jquery expert, so maybe things could done better, but I managed to retrieve a dialog box from the original onclick event. This is the code that makes things happen:

```
$('a.help').livequery(function(){
        var cl = $(this).attr('onclick');
        var str = cl.split("('").pop().split("')").shift();
        var arr = str.split("','");     
        if (arr[1] == '') {
            qvar = arr[0];
        }
        else {
            qvar = arr[0]+'&mod='+arr[1];
        }       
        $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
        $(this).attr('href', 'help_text.php?help='+qvar);

        var $link = $(this);        
        var $dialog = $('<div id="help-dialog"></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,                
                width: 500,
                modal: true         
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            var htitle = $dialog.find('.helpheader');
            htitle.hide();
            $dialog.dialog( 'option', 'title', htitle.text() ); 
            $dialog.find('.helpfooter').remove();
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

First I made a link from the onclick values and put it in the href attribute. That way I could get the contents of the page in the href link into the dialog.

There is one thing that I couldn't get to work. Inside the dialog content there are two links in the footer. For the time being I just removed the contents of the footer, but that is not what I eventually want.

One link is a close link. I tried to get it work with this code:

```
$dialog.find('.helpfooter a[onclick*="close"]');
closelink.removeAttr('onclick');
closelink.click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('close');
});
```

It is working but it also refreshes the mainpage and I want it to behave in the same way as the default closebutton in the topright corner of the dialog, so without refreshing the page. How can I do that?

The second link in the footer is a link to another (general) page. When this link is clicked I want to close the current dialog box and open a new one with the contents of the new page. Is that possible? And if so how can I do that.